# Is Application.onFirstStart event fired on application upgrade?

Tags: smartface.io

Is Application.onFirstStart event fired on application upgrade? If not, is there any way to do something only once on upgrade or on the first start after upgarde?

Answer (score 1):

onFirstStart will not run on update. 
You can use onStart function, inside this function you can control application.version in order to understand if application is upgraded or not.